# php preg_match character special characters ([ ] ( ) { } etc)

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

im new to preg_match, i know this character [ ] has meaning in preg_match, but how do I actually treat it as character that i really want to match?

For example:

```
$word = '[Hello], Im steve';
preg_match_all('/[Hello]/', $word, $match);
print_r($match)
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => H [1] => e [2] => l [3] => l [4] => o [5] => e [6] => e ) )
```

The above statement didnt match and return the real '[' and ']'
How to overcome this?

Comment: You must only escape the opening square bracket since it is used for opening a character class, escaping the closing square bracket is not needed in php.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for the extra clarification, both works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape it with a backslash `\`

```
preg_match_all('/\[Hello\]/', $word, $match); 

print_r($match);
```

**UPD:**

Case-insensitive match:  (`i` modifier after delimiter)

```
preg_match_all('/\[Hello\]/i', $word, $match);
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but how to perform case insensitivity match?

Comment: i mean even /\[hello\]/ , can match..sorry for newb question again